# How can we validate Apex Attribute values

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a component in which there are one attribute of type string. When I include this component into a VF page then I can set a any values to this attribute. Is there any validations in Salesforce that I can validate this values and not let the user save the page until it's changed.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear to me what kind of values you want to exclude from being entered as strings. You don't say if you're trying to prevent someone from pasting rich formatted text into your string or something along those lines, so I'm somewhat guessing here with my response. If you want to make certain the user only enters alphanumeric characters along with whitespace, you can create a validation rule using a regular-expression that checks for only those types of characters. Similarly, if there are specific characters you want to exclude, you can also check for those using a regular-expressions.

If you can be more specific about what string values you want to validate (e.g, time, dates, names, email addresses, etc), I'm confident we can provide you with more details on how to perform a particular type of validation. In the mean time, here's a link for general information on [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) and another to a very helpful free [utility for creating regular-expressions](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

If you're looking to "cast" values entered as strings into a particular sObject type, that's an entirely different matter. There are numerous solutions that have been posted around the web for utility classes that perform tasks of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform validation via javascript, there are some good jQuery plugins around for doing this. To use it, instead of calling an action directly from an `<apex:commandButton>` you should instead use apex action function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doValidation()
  {
    // do checks here
    if(somevield != valid value)
    {
      return false;
    }

    //etc. 

    return true;
  }

</script>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!theControllerAction}" name="callAction"/>

<apex:commandButton onclick="if(doValidation()) callAction();" value="Save"/>
```